# Error with PushPlugin when the App is in background

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm trying to implement a push notification app created with Cordava 3.3 using this: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin ; Basing me in this tutorial: www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql
But I have 2 basic problems the first is that the notification does not lead if the app is in background or is closed and the second is that the message reaches Undefined when the app is open in the foreground, could help, as far as I was reading may be due the format of the JSON response or parameters sent in the same.

Here is my code not take long: 
https://github.com/jedidas/Push

Answer (score 1):

I achieved a solution that is on file with the plugin "GCMIntentService.java" near line 80 is the next instruction

```
else {
    extras.putBoolean("foreground", false);

            // Send a notification if there is a message
            if (extras.getString("message") != null && extras.getString("message").length() != 0) {
                createNotification(context, extras);
            }
        }
```

discover you can change the "price" for what you want, for example change the "price" for "message" and everything was solved milagorsamente, explain:

we have this: 
. 1 $ message = array ("deprive" => $ message);

and read when I read it as: 
1. E.payload.message

gives us comes as undefined because payload.price.

In this sense, we have to file in the JAVA plugin

if (extras.getString ("message")! = null && extras.getString ("message"). length ()! = 0) {
                     createNotification (context, options); 
                 }

if that does not run because it is coming as "price" instead of "message". everything is solved when I change the "price" of SEND_MESSAGE.PHP for "message." thus not even need to modify the JAVA.

Comment: how do you solve this issue? It's happenning the same to me, [see my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767904/pushnotification-not-working-with-the-app-in-background)